# Invalid JMES search result type, only string is allowed

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, jmespath

I am trying to mount a Kubernetes secret via a `kubernetes_manifest` like this, however, `port` is a number `5342`

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "test" {
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1"
    "kind"       = "SecretProviderClass"
    "metadata" = {
      namespace = "test-namespace"
      "name"    = "test"
    }
    "spec" = {
      "provider" = "aws"
      "secretObjects" = [{
        "secretName" = "test"
        "type"       = "Opaque"
        data = [{
          "objectName" = "test123"
          "key"        = "port"
        }
]
      }]
      "parameters" = {
        objects = yamlencode([{
          objectName  = aws_secretsmanager_secret.test.name
          objectType  = "secretsmanager"
          objectAlias = "test"
          jmesPath = [{
            path        = "port"
            objectAlias = "test123"
          }]
        }])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I `terraform apply` this, I get the error:

> err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Invalid JMES search result type for path:port. Only string is allowed

Is there a way to mount `port` despite it being a number? Can I convert it to a string somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMESPath does have a [`to_string`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-string) function.

So, you can use a JMESPath query in the `path` field and do:

```
path        = "to_string(port)"
```